# ¿Cómo sumarle una un mes a la fecha actual del sistema?

Tags: java, date

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema para un gimnasio que calcule la fecha actual de inscripción y la de vencimiento.

En mi sistema tengo dos botones:

- Uno que calcula la fecha actual del sistema y la muestra en un Text Field (funciona).
- El otro intenta sumarle un mes a la fecha actual. Lo hace correctamente pero lo imprime en consola y necesito que lo muestre en otro Field Text pero me da un  error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Mi código:

```
private void botonMensualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //Calcula la fecha actual
    Date fecha = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar.setLenient(false);

    calendar.setTime(fecha); // Configuramos la fecha que se recibe
    calendar.add(calendar.MONTH, 1);  // numero de meses a añadir, o restar en caso de días<0

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/YYYY");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); //Imprime la 
    fecha en la consola 
    sdf.format(calendar.getTime());//Le da formato a la fecha 

    textoMembresiaVence.setText(sdf.format(sdf));   
}
```

Comment: El título no se corresponde con el mensaje de error/problema planteado en la pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y completes el [tour] para encontrar información sobre cómo mejorar tus publicaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Te estas pasando el parametro equivocado en la linea:

```
textoMembresiaVence.setText(sdf.format(sdf));
```

Deberia ser:

```
textoMembresiaVence.setText(calendar.getTime());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando coloco "textoMembresiaVence.setText(calendar.getTime());" Me da un error "Tipos de datos incompatibles: Date no se puede cambiar a String"

Comment: Le agrego: " textoMembresiaVence.setText(calendar.getTime().toString());" pero me sale un formato que no es

Comment: Estas usando el SimpleDateFormat que creaste?.... observa la imagen que hago uso de el. (sdf.format(calendar.getTime())) @JoséDaniel

Comment: No lo estaba utilizando...Funciono!! Muchas Gracias!!